# DATEADD and BETWEEN not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have the following code:

```
DECLARE @testDate date
--SET @testDate=dateadd(wk, 5830, 0)
SET @testDate='2011-09-26 00:00:00.000'

SELECT *
FROM dbo.timesheets
WHERE @testDate BETWEEN convert(datetime, start_dtm, 120) and convert(datetime, end_dtm, 120)

PRINT @testDate
```

It should convert the value 5830 back to the date format and then check between `start_dtm` and `end_dtm`

I have tested this by hard coding the value from the database in the above code and i still dont see any records.  The printed `@testdate` shows up like this: `2011-09-26`

I am creating a `week_ref` which i am passing via querystring. The timesheets report will then convert the `week_ref` eg, '5830' to the date and check if its between the `start_dtm` and `end_dtm`. In theory it should display results as its checking if values are between start and end.

Any ideas? or help on debugging?

**EDIT: row in the timesheets table:**

[image: Example row from timesheets table]

Here is the query i am trying to get working:

```
DECLARE @week_ref INT
DECLARE @weekDate date

set @weekDate=dateadd(wk,@week_ref,0)



SELECT     ts.staff_member_ref, sm.common_name, sm.department_name, DATENAME(MONTH, ts.start_dtm) + ' ' + DATENAME(YEAR, ts.start_dtm) AS month_name, 
                      ts.timesheet_cat_ref, cat.desc_long AS timesheet_cat_desc, grps.grouping_ref, grps.description AS grouping_desc, ts.task_ref, tsks.task_code, 
                      tsks.description AS task_desc, ts.site_ref, sits.description AS site_desc, ts.site_ref AS Expr1, 
                      CASE WHEN ts .status = 0 THEN 'Pending' WHEN ts .status = 1 THEN 'Booked' WHEN ts .status = 2 THEN 'Approved' ELSE 'Invalid Status' END AS site_status, 
                      ts.booked_time AS booked_time_sum,

start_dtm, CONVERT(varchar(20), start_dtm, 108) + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar(20), start_dtm, 103) AS start_dtm_text, booked_time,
end_dtm, CONVERT(varchar(20), end_dtm, 108) + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar(20), end_dtm, 103) AS end_dtm_text


FROM timesheets AS ts 

INNER JOIN timesheet_categories AS cat ON ts.timesheet_cat_ref = cat.timesheet_cat_ref 
INNER JOIN timesheet_tasks AS tsks ON ts.task_ref = tsks.task_ref 
INNER JOIN timesheet_task_groupings AS grps ON tsks.grouping_ref = grps.grouping_ref 
INNER JOIN timesheet_sites AS sits ON ts.site_ref = sits.site_ref 
INNER JOIN vw_staff_members AS sm ON ts.staff_member_ref = sm.staff_member_ref
--INNER JOIN week_list AS WL ON ts.timesheet_ref = WL.week_ref

--WHERE (ts.status IN (1, 2)) AND (cat.is_leave_category = 0)
--AND WL.week_ref=@week_ref AND WL.start_week BETWEEN ts.start_dtm AND ts.end_dtm

WHERE @weekDate <= convert(datetime, end_dtm, 120) 
AND @weekDate > convert(datetime, start_dtm, 120)



GROUP BY ts.staff_member_ref, sm.common_name, sm.department_name, DATENAME(MONTH, ts.start_dtm), DATENAME(YEAR, ts.start_dtm), ts.timesheet_cat_ref, 
                      cat.desc_long, grps.grouping_ref, grps.description, ts.status, ts.booked_time, ts.task_ref, tsks.task_code, tsks.description, ts.site_ref, sits.description, ts.start_dtm, 
                      ts.end_dtm
ORDER BY sm.common_name, timesheet_cat_desc, tsks.task_code, site_desc
```

Comment: Could you add the data type and example values for the columns start_dtm and end_dtm in the table timesheets?

Comment: Is there start_dtm < end_dtm?

Comment: Can you include some sample data? I just tried your existing query with some sample data and it seemed to work OK. (Also, what datatypes are your _dtm columns?)

Comment: Also, have you considered the possibility of end_dtm being set to null to represent a date range that hasn't ended? (Such a date range would not be selected by this query.)

Comment: I have added an edit to my original post showing a row from the timesheets table.

Comment: @sp-1986: 2011-09-26 is not between 2011-04-01 and 2011-04-01. If all your data has date ranges that do not include 2011-09-26, then your query is working correctly. Alternatively, try including some sample data where the specified date range **does** include 2011-09-26, or try changing `@testdate` to 2011-04-01.

Comment: @MarkBannister The value recorded in the timesheet is 1st April 2011 therefore the week date would be 28th March 2011 which is 5804. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you actually want:

```
DECLARE @testDate date
SET @testDate=dateadd(wk, 5804, 0)
--SET @testDate='2011-03-28 00:00:00.000'

SELECT *
FROM dbo.timesheets
WHERE @testDate <= convert(datetime, end_dtm, 120) and 
      dateadd(wk, 1, @testDate) > convert(datetime, start_dtm, 120)

PRINT @testDate
```

This version of the query tests whether any part of the records' date ranges is within the week beginning on `@testDate`.

Comment: Basically the week_ref is a number that determines the start of the week. It will always be Monday. So the query needs to just, "show-me-all-the-timesheets-from-the-week-based-on-the-week-ref" and yes it has to be less than or equal to the end date.

Comment: This wont work as @testDate should be INT and it cant convert INT to date?

Comment: Still having problems could you help? please.

Comment: @sp-1986: How can @testDate be INT? (It is a date in your original question.) If you want to supply a week number, the simplest way is to specify it as the second argument of the dateadd statement in the `SET @testDate` statement (as above, and as commented out in the original question). If you want to supply something other than a week number as an integer, you need to explain further.

Comment: Sorry i might have made a mistake. The @TestDate is actually a week_ref and that should be an INT. eg, 5854

Comment: @sp-1986: - where 5854 represents the week beginning 12 March 2012? The same principal applies: specify it as the second argument of the dateadd statement in the SET @testDate statement. ( Or add a second variable: `DECLARE @testWeek int; SET @testWeek=5854; DECLARE @testDate date;
SET @testDate=dateadd(wk, @testWeek, 0)` ).

Comment: I did this, it complained about not being able to convert an INT to DATE or something. Ill try tomorrow morning as don't have access. Appreciate it if you can check this page tomorrow for me?

Comment: Hi Mark, ive added the SP thats im working with. Added the second argument and still get no records. Have i done it correctly?

Comment: in fact, i think i have it working.. give me a few hours.. :)

Answer (score 2):

I have 2 queries that i want you to consider:

```
declare @timesheets table(start_dtm datetime, end_dtm datetime)

insert @timesheets values('2011-09-26', '2011-09-27')
insert @timesheets values('2011-09-28', '2011-09-29')


-- This will return 1 row
SELECT *
FROM @timesheets
WHERE dateadd(wk, 5830, 0) BETWEEN start_dtm and end_dtm

-- This will return both rows
SELECT *
FROM @timesheets
WHERE 5830 BETWEEN datediff(wk, 0, start_dtm) and datediff(wk, 0, end_dtm)
```

You should avoid converting/casting when it isn't nessasary.

Answer (score 1):

Based on edit this should work fine:

```
DECLARE @testDate datetime
SET @testDate='2011-09-26 00:00:00.000'

SELECT *
FROM dbo.timesheets
WHERE @testDate BETWEEN start_dtm and end_dtm
```

or you might have this problem (there is no time info and you just have one day:

```
     SELECT *
     FROM dbo.timesheets
     WHERE @testDate BETWEEN start_dtm and end_dtm 
  OR @testDate = start_dtm OR @testDate = end_dtm
```

---

Some variables are date type and some are datetime.  I would do it like this

```
DECLARE @testDate date
SET @testDate='2011-09-26 00:00:00.000'

SELECT *
FROM dbo.timesheets
WHERE @testDate BETWEEN cast(start_dtm as date) and cast(end_dtm as date)
```

or

```
DECLARE @testDate datetime
SET @testDate='2011-09-26 00:00:00.000'

SELECT *
FROM dbo.timesheets
WHERE @testDate BETWEEN cast(start_dtm as datetime) and cast(end_dtm as datetime)
```

Comment: thanks, but nothing shows up. start_dtm and end_dtm are datetime in the database.

Comment: added some edits to my post, showing a row from the timesheets table. Maybe ive missed something?

Comment: @sp-1986 - I made one change but you should consider that there are no records that match the criteria.